# How do I debug and solve the ValueError when integrating the Rev.ai API into the Python SpeechRecognition library?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I'm trying to add support for the [Rev.ai service](https://www.rev.ai/docs) into the [Python SpeechRecognition library](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition) using the [Rev.ai Python SDK](https://github.com/revdotcom/revai-python-sdk). I have written an integration function but when I try to use it in a simple application, I receive a ValueError. I suspect this could be due to an error in the input audio configuration and would like help to understand and resolve it.

My SpeechRecognition function is below:

```
    def recognize_rev_ai(self, audio_data, key=None, language="en"):
        """
        This function requires a Rev.ai account.
        """
        assert isinstance(audio_data, AudioData), "``audio_data`` must be audio data"
        assert key is None or isinstance(key, str), "``key`` must be ``None`` or a string"
        assert isinstance(language, str), "``language`` must be a string"

        try:
            from rev_ai.models import MediaConfig
            from rev_ai.streamingclient import RevAiStreamingClient
        except ImportError:
            raise RequestError('missing rev_ai module')

        config = MediaConfig('audio/x-raw', 'interleaved', 16000, 'S16LE', 1)

        raw_data = audio_data.get_raw_data(
            convert_rate=16000
        )

        if key is not None:
            streamclient = RevAiStreamingClient(key, config)
        try:
            with io.open(raw_data, 'rb') as stream:
                media_generator = [stream.read()]
            response_generator = streamclient.start(media_generator)
            for response in response_generator:
                print(response)

        except URLError as e:
            raise RequestError("recognition connection failed: {0}".format(e.reason))
```

Here is a sample script to demonstrate usage. I modeled it on an example from the SpeechRecognition code samples. This script fails with `ValueError: embedded null byte`. The full error traceback is included at the end.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone(sample_rate = 16000) as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
  print ('Rev thinks you said: ' + r.recognize_rev_ai(audio, 'KEY'))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Rev could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Rev error; {0}".format(e))
```

Full error traceback:

```
Say something!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 10, in <module>
    print ('Rev thinks you said: ' + r.recognize_rev_ai(audio, 'KEY'))
  File "/home/vikram/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 1431, in recognize_rev_ai
    with io.open(raw_data, 'rb') as stream:
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

I would appreciate some help debugging the above.

Comment: Have you tried to pass a raw data: `streamclient.start([raw_data])` as it is stated in the example: https://github.com/revdotcom/revai-python-sdk/blob/develop/examples/generator_streaming_example.py?

Comment: It would be a good idea to add the full error description.

Comment: @DibloDk I added the complete error.

Comment: @deeptowncitizen Thanks for your suggestion. It worked.